# call a function inside a constructor of an object instantiated in an another constructor

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
struct D{};
struct B{};

struct C
{
    C();
};

struct A
{
    A();
    B * b;
    C * c;
    D * d;

    static A& pInstance()
    {
        static A a;
        return a;
    }
};


A::A()
{
    b = new B;
    c = new C;
    d = new D;
}

C::C()
{
    A::pInstance().b;
}

int main()
{
    A::pInstance();

    std::cin.ignore();

}
```

Is there potentially any problems with the above case, as the C constructor call A field while A class not yet construted entirely.

I have this code in production. The application seems to crash randomly at starting, I am wondering if this can be due to this "poor" design.

Comment: Should the first line be `static A& A::pInstance()`, or the 2 invocations have the extra `A::`?

Comment: When you enter the constructor, the class already is completely constructed.

Comment: Such a question requires a complete example to be answered correctly. Please include the required declarations/definitions.

Comment: THis code won't compile for a number of reasons. Do you have a [SCCCE](http://sscce.org/) or should we close this?

Comment: @Guillaume07: You have, but the code is still littered with errors.

Comment: @JOhn: sorry i have re-edited now is good

Comment: @Guillaume07: This compiles. Thanks. Can I ask *why* you'd want to attempt such a thing? Purely for educational purposes?

Comment: @John: I have a code in production which this design. The application seems to crash randomly at starting, I am just wondering if this can be due to this "poor" design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's explicitly stated as *Undefined Behavior*: (§ 6.7/4) "If control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is being initialized, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 1):

> [Are] there potentially any problems with the above case, as the C constructor call A field while A class not yet constructed entirely.

Yes. This is likely to cause you problems as [the behaviour is undefined...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940127/78845)

You initialise an instance of `C`  before your `static` `A` (`a`) is fully constructed. `a` is then referenced in the `C`'s constructor. Since `a` is not constructed you could[<sup>*</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940127/78845) enter a recursive loop.

[This is what happens when you build this with g++.](http://ideone.com/529Ww)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will test another design and see if bug disappear (no crash on 5 days for instance). I am under windows with MSVC2010 compiler.